# How do I know if I've reached the end ODataFeed with Olingo

Tags: odata, olingo

I'm using Olingo to traverse a list of feeds. I was wondering how do I know if I've reached the end of the feed page? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This depends how you are doing paging.  If the server is limiting the number of results for you, you should get a "next" link at the bottom of the feed to indicate there are more values.

Some limited documentation here: (Search for the word "next").
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/operations

If you are doing paging yourself, such as: .../EntitySet?$top=10&$skip=1

You can add "$inlinecount=allpages" to get the total number of items.  Then you could do some simple math to determine if you are on the last page.

Hope this helps.